# add a text (as e.g. reference) at bottom of beamer slide?

Tags: beamer

How to add a text (as e.g. reference) at bottom of beamer slide?

I just want text, no need for the moment of bib or biblatex (too complicated for me now).

Here my example:

```
\documentclass[14pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Slides}
\author{Username}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 3}
\begin{itemize}
\item line1
\begin{itemize}
\item item1
\item item2
\item item3, here I would like to have a reference below, at bottom of slide, in the box on left side.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If it is a bibliographic reference, you can use `\footcite` from `biblatex`.

Answer (score 1):

using a footnote:

```
\documentclass[14pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Slides}
\author{Username}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 3}
\begin{itemize}
\item line1
\begin{itemize}
\item item1
\item item2
\item item3, here I would like to have a reference below, at bottom of slide, in the box on left side.\footnote{text at bottom of slide}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```